# jQuery Event Handler method - Mixing pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

jQuery event method come in pairs - `on()` and `off()`, `live()` and `die()`, `bind()` and `unbind()`.

My question is, can we mix pairs? For example attach a event with `on()` and remove it with `unbind()`?

The documentation suggests to me that it is best practise to use the corresponding method, `bind()` with `unbind()` http://api.jquery.com/unbind/, but it doesn't explicitly say you can't mix them.
It seems to me as `live()`/`die()` are interchangeable with `on()`/`off()`, and `bind()`/`unbind()` with shorthand methods like `click()`/`change()`.

Could someone also explain how events are attached, referenced and stored?
As I understand it, jQuery events are stored in a array and can be referenced via `obj.event("name")`. Do `on()`/`off()` and `bind()`/`unbind()` use different arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.unbind()` to unbind events registered with `.on()` and vise versa. Check it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVyZOL

But using `.on()` and .off() is the preferred way of binding and unbinding events:

> Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind().
>   (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to
>   attach and remove event handlers on elements.)

--

> how events are attached, refference and stored?

jQuery attaches events using addEventListener() and attachEvent() according to browser support. [check jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/external/qunit/qunit.js#L2251-L2261)

And as you said jQuery events :

> are stored in a array and can be reffrenced via
>   obj.event("name").